# S3 Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to use [blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) to blur user uploaded images, and I'm storing the images on Amazon S3. I've set up what I think to be the correct CORS configuration, but the images can't be blurred and I get this error in the browser:

```
  Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Here's my CORS configuration:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
  </CORSConfiguration>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Any chance of posting a sanitized version of your html/js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a suspicion that you're not using the correct S3 endpoint address format that's required for CORS support.

i.e. S3 buckets support both of these formats:

1. `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/object`
2. `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object`

But only the first URL will work with CORS according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#example-scenarios-cors):

> with CORS, you can configure your bucket to explicitly enable cross-origin requests from website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Ahh, I'll try that now and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I've just done it. Basically, you can follow the steps to edit your S3 bucket permissions and make ir work. If you need any further help, leave a comment bellow.

1) Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/

2) In the Buckets list, open the bucket whose properties you want to view and click "add CORS configuration"

[image: amazon-screen-shot]

3) Write the rules you are willing to add in between the tags `<CORSConfiguration>`

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can learn more about rules at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

4) Specify crossorigin='anonymous' on the image you'll use in your canvas

Comment: `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` did it for me